# How does yui3 io-form return failure or success?

Tags: php, javascript, yui3

I have the following:

```
YUI().use("io-form",
    function(Y) {
        var cfg = {
            method: 'POST',
            form: {
                id: 'subscribe-form',
                useDisabled: false
            }
        };
        function login() {
            Y.io('process.php', cfg);
            Y.on('io:success', onSuccess, this);
            Y.on('io:failure', onFailure, this);
        };
        function onSuccess(id,response,args) {
            document.getElementById('myformmsg').innerHTML = response.responseText;
            document.forms['myform'].reset();
        };
        function onFailure(id,response,args) {
            document.getElementById('myformmsg').innerHTML = "Error, retry...";
            document.forms['myform'].reset();
        };
        Y.on('click', login, '#myformbutton', this, true);
});
```

How does yui know whether to go into onSucces of onFailure. What do I have to return from PHP?

Comment: Does anyone have a neat way to pass back an array that states the error?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the header returned http status code.
let say status code 200, it will goes to onSuccess.
let say status code 500 (internal server error), it will goes to onFailure.

List of HTTP status code here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

If you have some fatal error in php, it will still returns status 200 because the request is successful.

If you would like to handle php errors, I would suggest you to have an json return like everytime on success:

```
{
  status: 0, // Let say 0 for OK, -1 for Error, you can define more by yourself
  results: <anything you want here>,
  errors: <errors message/errors code for your ajax handler to handle>
}
```

it can be done in php like this:

```
$response = array(
    'status' => 0,
    'results' => 'something good ...',
    'errors' => 'error message if status is -1'
);
echo json_encode($response);
```

In your javascript, you will be handling like this:

```
function onSuccess(id,response,args) {
     var responseObj = Y.JSON.parse(response);

     if (responseObj.status === 0) { 
         // Request and process by php successful
     }
     else {
         // Error handling
         alert(responseObj.errors);
     }
};
```

Remember, if you wanted to use Y.JSON, you need to include 'json-parse', example:

```
YUI().use('json-parse', , function (Y) {
    // JSON is available and ready for use. Add implementation
    // code here.
});
```